# How to pass You need permission when access webapp be create by google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two Google Apps Scripts like this:

---

Script A:

This is a webapp. I use it like a web api. Depend on parameter I will return data what I read from a SpreadSheet only I can access and I will add or edit data in this SpreadSheet.

I published it with following options:

Execute as me

Who has access to the web app:Anyone

---

Script B:(in a SpreadSheet)

I use this SpreadSheet like a input form. And I will request to script A by UrlFetchApp function.

---

The problem:
When I use UrlFetchApp function, the response content is a html like following image. I think this is a request access dialog what will send a request mail to script A owner. I tried to share script B project to test user. It work fine. But I want to show html dialog and do something for test user can send mail normally.

---

**Questions:**

How can I show this html content on a dialog in SpreadSheet B?

If have another way which I must not share script A project to other one, tell me please! Because they can see my script A when I shared it to them.

[image: You need permission]

I have used ScriptApp.getOAuthToken to verified webapp like this:

```js
function requestAPI(request_parameter_string) {
    var param = {
        method      : "get",
        headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
        followRedirects : true,
        muteHttpExceptions:true
    };
    
    Logger.log("run to this");
    var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/" + api_id + "/exec?" + request_parameter_string;
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,param);
    if(response.getContentText() != "Success"){
        return response.getContentText();
    }
}
```

Comment: In your deployment condition of Web Apps, in order to access to Web Apps, the access token is required to be used. So the login screen is returned. If you don't want to use the access token, how about modifying from ``Who has access to the web app: Anyone`` to ``Who has access to the web app: Anyone, even anonymous``? If you are required to know about how to use the access token, can you provide your current script of Script "B"? By the way, when you modify your script of Web Apps, please update the version and redeploy Web Apps. By this, the latest script is reflected to Web Apps.

Comment: @Tanaike I have used access token. I added my code to my question content. I cannot use option `Who has access to the web app: Anyone, even anonymous`.  It is dangerous.

Comment: Thank you for updating your question. I posted an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that is not useful for your situation, please tell me. I would like to think of other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Your situation is as follows.

- Web Apps is deployed as `Execute as me` snd `Who has access to the web app:Anyone`.
- You want to make users access to your Web Apps using the access token.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- If you access to Web Apps that you are owner, you can access using the access token.
- If other users access to your Web Apps, **when the project file which deployed Web Apps is shared to users**, users can access using the access token.

  - When the file is not shared, such error occurs.
  - If you use the container-bound script, please share it.
  - If you use the standalone script, please share it.
- For the access token, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` is required to be included in the scopes.

#### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Your solution is exact. Only one thing that I don't want whom Web App is shared for, can see Web App script code. If there is not a solution for this, I think I will use a secret key to verify between script A and script B, and deploy web app as `Who has access to the web app: Anyone, even anonymous`

Comment: @ONLAEG In my experience, it has been found that it was required to be shared the project to access to Web Apps from April 11, 2018, when Web Apps is deployed as ``Execute as me`` and ``Who has access to the web app:Anyone``. Before it, it was not required to share. I think that this update is due to the issue of security. If you don't want to share the script, also I think that the method using secret key to Web Apps deployed with ``Anyone, even anonymous`` is better, as you are thinking. I apologize that I was not useful for your situation.

Comment: No, your solution not really match in my situation, but your GitHub site is very helpful. After reading it, I sure that other users cannot access to my web app without project be shared. Amazing helpful site. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @ONLAEG I'm glad for the comment. Thank you, too.

Comment: @ONLAEG Now I remembered one way. Although I'm not sure whether this is useful for your situation, if users can have a chance to open the endpoint of Web Apps using the browser, users can directly access to Web Apps without sharing the script. But in this case, users are required to login to Google using own account.